# let statement in loop doesn't work as expected in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, let

I am trying some example in ECMAScript 6. That is working differently compared to other browsers. This returns `true` in Firefox, but it returns `false` in IE. Why is this working different in Internet Explorer?

```
let callbacks = []
for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  callbacks[i] = function () { console.log(i); return i * 2 }
}
console.log(callbacks[0]() === 0);
console.log(callbacks[1]() === 2);
console.log(callbacks[2]() === 4);
```

Comment: IE doesn't support ES6 fully.

Comment: ok.I does not show any errors. But it returns the value wrongly.

Comment: wrong because IE doesn't support ecma6 very well

Comment: It's a known problem with IE that `let` within the `for(...)` initialisation doesn't work as it should. The simplest workaround is to add `let j = i;` as the first line inside the `{ }` block and then use `j` within your function - that gives the result you expect.

Comment: It's surprising... they should avoid supporting the `let` keyword if they can't implement it as per specifications.

Comment: Actually it's not just IE. **No single javascript engine, either in the browser or server currently support the complete ES6 spec**. If you want to use ES6 features either use only the very limited subset that has wide browser support or use a transpiler like babel. If you want to use pure js, use ES5. ES6 cannot be used as is in production. It's OK for hobby projects because you only need it to run in your own browser so you can use the small subset your browser supports. But it's not OK for real production code.

Comment: Remember, we've only gotten full ES5 support 3 years ago (2013)

Comment: @pietro909 It IS implemented according to the specs. The OP's problem has to do with `for`, which supports an additional scope in ES6.

Comment: @slebetman Safari 10 has 100% support. And all major browsers have  very wide support. Why shouldn't someone use ES6 in production code if the customer uses, say, Chrome?

Comment: @zeroflagL sorry I might have misunderstood: so the problem is the implementation of `for` rather than `let`?

Comment: @pietro909 You could put it that way, yes. `let` is about scope. In the OP's example it's not within the `for` block, so the example cannot work simply by using `let`. We need an additional scope between the block and the outside of the for statement. As of ES6 the `for` statement creates such a block.

Answer (score 4):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) IE11 kind of supports *let*:

> *let* variables are not bound separately to each iteration of *for* loops

Comment: notably, the let variables created INSIDE the for's body seems to work fine. it's only the let-variables created in the for() constructor that seems to be broken. eg this works fine: `for(;;){let i;}` and this is broken: `for(let i;;){}`

Answer (score 0):

for people looking for a quick workaround for IE11,

```js
let callbacks = []
for (let ie11i = 0; ie11i <= 2; ie11i++) {
  /*IE11 let bug bypass*/
  let i = ie11i;
  callbacks[i] = function () { console.log(i); return i * 2 }
}
console.log(callbacks[0]() === 0);
console.log(callbacks[1]() === 2);
console.log(callbacks[2]() === 4);
```

- will work the same in IE11 as any other browser, as long as you remember to use `i`  instead of `ie11i` inside the loop.