# AddEventListener function variable scope issue in IE 11

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a function that works fine in Chrome, but testing in IE, it cannot access the variable outside of the function:

```
if (cipher[i].solved == false){
    bottom.classList.add("HighlightBox");            
    bottom.classList.add("bg-warning");
    bottom.addEventListener('click', function(){
        // IE cannot access cipher[i] in this function
        cipher[i].solved = true;
        hintsUsed++;
        runHint(true);
        populateAnswerKey(puzzleWord, cipher, false);
        populatePuzzleBoard(puzzleWord, cipher);

    });
}
```

cipher[i] is not able to be accessed by IE (though it works fine in Chrome). Is there a way to pass cipher[i] through, or another easy adjustment I can make so that IE can access that variable when it creates the event listener?

**EDIT**: After more testing, it seems that the issue is that IE does not retain the value of the iterator [i]. It always remains one higher than the final pass through regardless of which event is clicked. Chrome can retain the iterator's value.

**EDIT2**: https://www.dan-teacher.com/cryptogram/41SXLPS1 - This is the game. It works in Chrome, but fails in (my version) of IE when I click "Use Hint" and then click one of the boxes.

Comment: Since IE generally have no such issue, you might have been used something it doesn't support, so provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue

Comment: *Chrome can retain the iterator's value* I doubt this... please share a working snippet.

Comment: Your code is wrong, not the browser! You have this code part inside a loop right? How did you declared 'i'? With 'let' or with 'var'? There are different ways to solve it but your code is definitively wrong if this is inside a loop.

Comment: https://www.dan-teacher.com/cryptogram/41SXLPS1

Comment: @Adriano - I'm using "let" to declare i. Anything else breaks the code.

Comment: `let` statement compatibility is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/let-statement-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[let statement in loop doesn't work as expected in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159669/let-statement-in-loop-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie)

"let" has issues in Internet Explorer. The simple workaround was to change:

```
for (let i = 0, i < cipher.length; i++){
    // code  
}
```

to

```
for (let k = 0, k < cipher.length; k++){
    let i = k;
    // code  
}
```